# Connecting to the database SQL Server for beginners

Tags: asp.net, .net, database-connection

Just like to ask, I want to create a blog with ASP.NET as a practice to get better. I came from PHP btw.

Anyway I'm stuck because I don't know what's the way most .NET programmers use to connect to the database. I'm planning on using LINQ.

Any tutorial/books and also websites that would point me to the right dorection would really help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The way most .NET programmers use to connect to databases is [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021.aspx), included with the Microsoft .NET Framework. Here some useful [code examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx).

LINQ ist not designed as a replacement for ADO.NET, LINQ provides a uniform programming model for any kind of data. With it, you can query and manipulate data by using a model that is independent of data sources.

```
var query =
    from c in Customers
    where c.Country == "Usa"
    select c.CompanyName;

foreach (string name in query)
    Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET developers use [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021.aspx) to connect to relational databases. This is the low level API. [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) provides an ORM on the top of ADO.NET that could map relational tables to objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new i will advise you to start with linq, but before that you should learn a little bit about ADO.Net, and whats better then msdn tutorials:

ADO.Net:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161165.aspx

Linq:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246861/LINQ-to-Entities-Basic-Concepts-and-Features